# css error on popup appearing

Tags: css, popup, margin, padding

I have a gallery plugin. If I click on another image, or in a arrow, a popup will appear.
The problem is that whem the popup is opened, the plugin gallery moves down on the page.
What is the css problem?
How can I fix it?

here my plugin:

```
http://judopassion.com/wordpress/?p=274
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a lot going on here, so I'll try and simplify the steps you need to take.

```
<div id="box">...
```

Needs to be a *child* of

```
<div id="gallery-1">....
```

So you would have:

```
<div id="gallery-1">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Add `position:relative;` to `gallery-1`.

Your `#box` styles are really, really messy. You need to delete `left:` and `top:` instructions from the CSS for `#box`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added top property on pop-up appearing, and removed it when is closed:

```
$("gallery-1").css("top","-xxem");
```

I can't use GeorgeBuckingham solutions, because the plugin don't not allow it. Thanks anyway.